# Is it possible to re-assign audio jacks in Linux?

Tags: audio

I've been back and forth between Windows and varying distributions of Linux for years now, however I recently (and hopefully finally) settled on Arch Linux. The only thing is I haven't been able to find a way to re-assign my audio jacks like I could in Windows using the HDA tool. I have a 5.1 surround sound system and I'm using the onboard audio, however I can't figure out how I re-assign all of the ports to be output instead of input so I can get the 5.1 actually acting like a 5.1 and not a stereo system.

The three plugs from my sound system are Front, Rear and Center/Sub. The jacks in my computer are the three standard ones - Pink/Green/Blue (Headphones / Audio / Microphone?)

Is there any way I can get this working? Reassigning can't be THAT hard!

Oh yeah, and I'm using some really strange ALSA/PulseAudio hybrid. I *think* I'm using ALSA, but /etc/asound.conf reports affiliation with Pulseaudio:

```
# Use PulseAudio by default
pcm.!default {
  type pulse
}

ctl.!default {
  type pulse
}

# Explicit PulseAudio device
pcm.pulse {
  type pulse
}

ctl.pulse {
  type pulse
}

# vim:set ft=alsaconf:
```

Comment: This "hybrid" is very much normal. ALSA-using programs get transparently redirected to PulseAudio (and PulseAudio itself uses ALSA to interface with the hardware). If programs were allowed to bypass Pulse and access hardware via ALSA directly, both would break.

Comment: @grawity: Thanks for the heads up there, I was concerned I'd broken something somehow! :P